# protobuf-net : enum type conversion error

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

```
namespace MyNamespace                                               
{       

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        EnumName1 = 1,    
        EnumName2 = 2,
        ...

    [ProtoContract(Name=@"MyClassProto")]                                               
    [Serializable]                                                                                  
    public class MyClass : IExtensible                                              
    {                                                                                                                                           
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"MyEnumProperty", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(1)]                                                     
        public MyEnum MyEnumProperty;                               
        ...



  var myObjectIn = new MyClass
  {
      MyEnumProperty = MyEnum.EnumName1,
      ...
  };

  MyClass myObjectOut;
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
      ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, myObjectIn);
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      myObjectOut = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(stream);
  }
```

> System.InvalidCastException : Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to
>   'MyNamespace.MyEnum'.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this still happen if you set `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.AutoCompile = false;` initially?  I tried to reproduce this in a fiddle, but could not: see https://dotnetfiddle.net/YTaKDJ.  However, for security reasons https://dotnetfiddle.net does not support `Reflection.Emit()` so I had to disable auto compilation - and when I did the bug was not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I am using protobuf-net v2.1.0, and depending on approach I get two distinct `ProtoException`s. Either `No wire-value is mapped to the enum MyEnum`, or `No parameterless constructor found`. Reasons are: the default int value 0 is not a constant in your enum type, or you haven't assigned a default value to it in a parameter constructor.

Workaround (logical or):

```
public enum MyEnum { EnumName1 = 1, EnumName2 = 2, @default = 0 }
```

or

```
public MyClass() { MyEnumProperty = MyEnum.EnumName1 }
```

From [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)

> 1. An enum declaration that does not explicitly declare an underlying
>      type has an underlying type of int. If the enum member is the first enum member declared in the enum type, its associated value is zero.
> 2. Enums are used for “multiple choice” scenarios, in which a runtime
>      decision is made from a fixed number of choices that are known at
>      compile-time

So, your enum with a runtime value you haven't defined as a compile-time constant, imo, is a bad enum.